# How do I get my deck of cards to deal the correct suit?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make is so when you click on a button, it displays a deck of cards. I have a button for each suit, so when you click on it, it deals the suit. I've gotten it to deal Hearts but when I try and deal Diamonds, it still displays hearts. What am I doing wrong? How would I go about displaying my diamonds?

```js
var heart = true;
var diamond = true;
var suit = "";

function card(name,suit,value) {
    this.name = name;
    this.suit = suit;
    this.value = value;
}

var deck = [
    new card('Ace', 'Hearts',11),
    new card('Two', 'Hearts',2),
    new card('Three', 'Hearts',3),
    new card('Four', 'Hearts',4),
    new card('Five', 'Hearts',5),
    new card('Six', 'Hearts',6),
    new card('Seven', 'Hearts',7),
    new card('Eight', 'Hearts',8),
    new card('Nine', 'Hearts',9),
    new card('Ten', 'Hearts',10),
    new card('Jack', 'Hearts',10),
    new card('Queen', 'Hearts',10),
    new card('King', 'Hearts',10),
    new card('Ace', 'Diamonds',11),
    new card('Two', 'Diamonds',2),
    new card('Three', 'Diamonds',3),
    new card('Four', 'Diamonds',4),
    new card('Five', 'Diamonds',5),
    new card('Six', 'Diamonds',6),
    new card('Seven', 'Diamonds',7),
    new card('Eight', 'Diamonds',8),
    new card('Nine', 'Diamonds',9),
    new card('Ten', 'Diamonds',10),
    new card('Jack', 'Diamonds',10),
    new card('Queen', 'Diamonds',10),
    new card('King', 'Diamonds',10),
    new card('Ace', 'Clubs',11),
    new card('Two', 'Clubs',2),
    new card('Three', 'Clubs',3),
    new card('Four', 'Clubs',4),
    new card('Five', 'Clubs',5),
    new card('Six', 'Clubs',6),
    new card('Seven', 'Clubs',7),
    new card('Eight', 'Clubs',8),
    new card('Nine', 'Clubs',9),
    new card('Ten', 'Clubs',10),
    new card('Jack', 'Clubs',10),
    new card('Queen', 'Clubs',10),
    new card('King', 'Clubs',10),
    new card('Ace', 'Spades',11),
    new card('Two', 'Spades',2),
    new card('Three', 'Spades',3),
    new card('Four', 'Spades',4),
    new card('Five', 'Spades',5),
    new card('Six', 'Spades',6),
    new card('Seven', 'Spades',7),
    new card('Eight', 'Spades',8),
    new card('Nine', 'Spades',9),
    new card('Ten', 'Spades',10),
    new card('Jack', 'Spades',10),
    new card('Queen', 'Spades',10),
    new card('King', 'Spades',10)
];


//hearts
$("#btnHeart").click(function () {
    if (heart == true) {
        heart = false;
        // pass 0
        dealHearts(0);
    }
});

function dealHearts(h) {
    if (h < 13) {
        displayHeart = deck[h];
        $("<img>").attr('alt', displayHeart.name + ' of ' + displayHeart.suit )
            .attr('src', 'images/cards/' + displayHeart.suit + '/' + displayHeart.name + '.jpg' )
            .appendTo('#heart')
            .hide()
            .fadeIn('slow')
            .delay(1000)
            .fadeOut('slow', function() {
                $('#heart').empty();
                h++;
                dealHearts(h);
            });
    } else {
        $("<img>").attr('alt', 'Done playing hearts.')
            .attr('src', 'images/check_sm.png' )
            .appendTo('#heart')
            .hide()
            .fadeIn('slow')
            .delay(1000)
            .fadeOut('slow', function() {
                $('#heart').empty();
                heart = true;
            });
    }
}
//End of hearts
//Diamonds
$("#btnDiamond").click(function(){
    if (diamond == true){
        diamond = false;
        dealDiamonds(0);
    }
});

function dealDiamonds(d) {
    if(d < 13) {
        displayDiamonds = deck[d];
        $("<img>").attr('alt', displayDiamonds.name + ' of ' + displayDiamonds.suit )
        .attr('src', 'images/cards/' + displayDiamonds.suit + '/' + displayDiamonds.name + '.jpg' )
        .appendTo('#diamond')
        .hide()
        .fadeIn('slow')
        .delay(1000)
        .fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('#diamond').empty();
            d++;
            dealDiamonds(d);
        });
    } else {
        $("<img>").attr('alt', 'Done playing diamonds.')
                  .attr('src', 'images/check_sm.png' )
                  .appendTo('#diamond')
                  .hide()
                  .fadeIn('slow')
                  .delay(1000)
                  .fadeOut('slow', function(){
                      $('#diamond').empty();
                      diamond = true;
                  });
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=”utf-8”>
        <title>A4_Deal Cards</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/deal.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <h1>Click to reveal your cards</h1>
            <div id="cardDisplay">
                <div class="hand" id="heart">
                </div>
                <div class="hand" id="diamond">
                </div>
                <div class="hand" id="club">
                </div>
                <div class="hand" id="spade">
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type ="button" id="btnHeart" value ="Hearts"/>
            <input type ="button" id="btnDiamond" value ="Diamonds"/>
            <input type ="button" id="btnClub" value ="Clubs"/>
            <input type ="button" id="btnSpade" value ="Spades"/>
            <div id="deck">
                <img src="images/deck_small.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/deal.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to rewrite everything for a more elegant solution, you can just add 12 to the index of the deck when dealing diamonds diamonds. This method will not if you end up shuffling the deck however.

```
function dealDiamonds(d) {
    if (d < 13) {
        displayDiamonds = deck[d + 12];
        //...
    } else {
        //...
    }
}
```

A more elegant solution would be to have a function that gets a specific card of a suit that doesn't rely on the deck being in a specific order.

```
function dealDiamonds(d) {
    if (d < 13) {
        displayDiamonds = getCardOfSuit('Diamonds', d);
        //...
    } else {
        //...
    }
}

function getCardOfSuit(suit, index) {
    //filter the deck to only the deck of a certain suit
    let suitDeck = deck.filter((card) => card.suit == suit);

    //returns the card (0 - 12) based on the second parameter
    return suitDeck[index];
}
```